# jquery a way to wait until a click command is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, sequence

I want to launch this three commands sequencially :

1. e.off('accordionchange')
2. $(this).click()
3. e.on('accordionchange', majIconeBtnTDrl)

I made this command with *when* and *then* in **jquery** for this purpose :

```
$.when(e.off('accordionchange'))
  .then($.when($(this).click())
  .then(e.on('accordionchange', majIconeBtnTDrl)));
```

it does not work

Comment: Please [define "it does not work"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). `e.off` is synchronous, it doesn't return a Promise, there's no point adding `.then` to it. Also, `$.when($(this).click())` is not at all how you [add a click listener in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/)... And adding a click listener doesn't return a Promise either, so there's no point chaining `.then()` to it either.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's hard to tell as the current logic makes no sense; event handlers/triggers do not return promises. It also seems to be a code smell to need to unbind an event handler, trigger another event and then rebind the original event.

Answer (score 1):

The `click` method has no way to determine when all the event handlers (nor any asynchronous functions triggered by those event handlers) have completed.

The sort of problem you could solve with this type of approach would generally best be solved by avoiding interacting with the click event in the first place.